# react-signature-canvas not working in ant design Modal

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

I am facing an issue when I put my SignaturePad inside of ant design component library "Modal" component, it is not able to generate the base64 image.

When the code reaches the trim function in the signaturepad, the sign will be "data:". But if i remove the Modal tags, it will return "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoxxxxx...." which is the normal behaviour. Is this due to the signature library not working well in ant design Modal?

Below is the code:

```js
import { Form, Modal } from 'antd';

const FormComponent = () => {
  const [form] = Form.useForm();

  return (

      <Modal
        title="Signature Form"
        open={true}>
        <div>
          <Form
            form={form}
          >
            <div>
              <SignaturePad
                name="signature"
                title="Signature"
                setFieldValue={(fieldName, value) => {
                  formSign.setFieldsValue({ [fieldName]: value });
                }}
                status={undefined}
                skipValidation={false}
              />
            </div>
          </Form>
        </div>
      </Modal>
  );
);
```

```js
import React, { useRef, RefObject } from 'react';
import SignaturePad from 'react-signature-canvas';
import { Button, Form } from 'antd';

interface SignaturePadProps {
  name: string;
  title: string;
  setFieldValue: (fieldName: string, value: any) => void;
  status?: 'error' | 'success';
  skipValidation?: boolean;
}

const SignaturePad: React.FC<SignaturePadProps> = ({
  name,
  title,
  setFieldValue,
  status,
  skipValidation,
}) => {
  const ref: RefObject<SignaturePad> = useRef<SignaturePad>(null);
  const isErrorBorder = status === 'error' ? 'signing-error-border' : '';

  const trim = () => {
    if (ref.current) {
      let sign = ref.current.toDataURL('image/png');
      setFieldValue(name, sign);
    }
  };

  const clear = () => {
    if (ref.current) {
      ref.current.clear();
      setFieldValue(name, '');
    }
  };

  return (
    <Form.Item
      {...{
        labelCol: {
          span: 4,
        }
      }}
      label={title}
      name={name}
      rules={[{ required: !skipValidation, message: 'This field is required' }]}
      valuePropName="data-url"
    >
      <section className='sign_form'>
        <SignaturePad
          onEnd={trim}
          canvasProps={{
            className: `sign_canvas ${isErrorBorder}`,
          }}
          ref={ref}
        />
        <Button onClick={clear} className='clear-btn'>
          Clear
        </Button>
      </section>
    </Form.Item>
  );
};

export default SignaturePad;
```